# How to get custom attributes from customer via SOAP API?

Tags: api, soap, eav, magento-1.6

I have a few custom attributes to extend the customer with bank account information. The attributes are stored in `mage_eav_attribute` table. How can I get them via the **SOAP API**?

Comment: Have you tried to provide the attribute codes as specified in the documentation. If you did: are you sure the attributes have been added to the customer entity properly? Which version of Magento (EE/CE, version number) and which SOAP API version are you using?

Comment: It's Magento CE 1.6.2 and the attributes are non standard.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to specify them?

[customer.info](http://www.magentocommerce.com/api/soap/customer/customer.info.html) looks like to have a third attribute which allows you to pass an array of requested attributes. I have no clue about SOAP, so I might be wrong, but if the attributes are not returned, `\Mage_Customer_Model_Api_Resource::_isAllowedAttribute` might filter them.

Good luck.